# Add more branch in AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline to start the pipeline every time there is a push on two specific branches

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codeartifact

I created a stack in which there is this resource for the creation of a pipeline that every time a push is made on the "master" branch started the pipeline:

```
  CodeCommitBranch:
    Type: String
    Description: branch name
    Default: master
    AllowedValues:
      - develop
      - release
      - master

CodePipeline:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${Constructor}-${ApplicationID}-codepipeline'
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref CodePipelineS3BucketName
        Type: S3
      RestartExecutionOnUpdate: true
      RoleArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${CodePipelineRoleName}'
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: Source
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeCommit
                Version: 1
              RunOrder: 1
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceArtifact
              Configuration:
                BranchName: !Ref CodeCommitRepoBranch
                PollForSourceChanges: false
                RepositoryName: !GetAtt 
                  - CodeCommitRepo
                  - Name
        - Name: Deploy-Dev
          Actions:
            - Name: Deploy-Dev
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeBuild
                Version: 1
              RunOrder: 2
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceArtifact
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: DeployArtifactDev
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeDeployDev
        - Name: Deploy-Int
          Actions:
            - Name: IntPromotionApproval
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Approval
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: Manual
                Version: 1
              RunOrder: 3
            - Name: Deploy-Int
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeBuild
                Version: 1
              RunOrder: 31
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceArtifact
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: DeployArtifactInt
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeDeployInt
```

I was wondering if it was possible to add an action within the same resource that starts the same pipeline when a push occurs on the "develop" branch. So ultimately the pipeline starts both when there is a push on "master" and on "develop".

Answer (score 2):

Multi brach pipeline configuration is not yet supported by AWS CodePipeline. So ideally you need to create another pipeline for your `develop` branch.

Your pipeline is configured with CloudWatch event. A `CloudWatch event rule` is automatically configured for your pipeline

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.codecommit"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "CodeCommit Repository State Change"
  ],
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:codecommit:us-west-2:80398EXAMPLE:MyTestRepo"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "referenceType": [
      "branch"
    ],
    "referenceName": [
      "master",
      "develop"
    ]
  }
}
```

If the above event rule is configured with your pipeline, then it trigger for both `master` and `develop` branch changes. But your pipeline is configured for your master branch. So in CodeBuild, your master branch content will be available in `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR` location

> CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR The directory path that CodeBuild uses for the build
> (for example, /tmp/src123456789/src).

To use a single pipeline for two branches then you need to develop and add your own logic in `buildspec.yml` file to checkout to the develop branch and perform the build there after.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would not try to build using the same pipeline for more than one branch. The trigger is the push to the branch that fires a Cloud Watch event that in turn kicks of the rest of the pipeline. So to try and kick of the pipeline from many different branches is not good.